# Android query in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm executing a query to fetch data from 2 tables and display them in a ListView.
I wrote this code, but there are syntax errors that I can not solve.

```
String tab_query = "SELECT _id,n_to,date,sal FROM Table1 ORDER BY sal ASC" + 
("SUM(field1)-SUM(field2) FROM Table2 " + 
"WHERE "+Table2Table.DATA+" BETWEEN "+FirstdDayOfYear+" AND "+dayOfWeek+")");
```

Comment: even so syntax error: near ASC SUM

Comment: Syntax error from where?  Java compiler or sqlite engine?  If the java compiles, add a statement to print out the complete query string to a debug console or something so that you can see it, and maybe identify where the syntax error lies.

Answer (score 1):

The result of your string concatenation omits a space between "ASC" and "SUM", so the final query winds up being "SELECT _id,n_to,date,sal FROM Table1 ORDER BY sal ASCSUM(field1)-SUM(field2) FROM Table2 ...

You also have mismatched parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

I think part of it is the first left paren is outside the quotes. Try this:

```
String tab_query = "SELECT _id,n_to,date,sal FROM Table1 ORDER BY sal ASC" + " 
(SUM(field1)-SUM(field2) FROM Table2 " + 
"WHERE "+Table2Table.DATA+" BETWEEN "+FirstdDayOfYear+" AND "+dayOfWeek+")");
```

Comment: There's a parentheses problem, but he's got a matching closing parenthesis at the end of the Java statement (though that could've been put there by his IDE).

Comment: even so I get syntax error "(" even though I always take off my syntax error.